# Dynamiclly putting heading text into textarea after click

Tags: jquery, variables, button, text, textarea

basically i have a button and after click i wanted to automatically select subject in select list (which it does) and take h3 and h5 text and put that into textarea.

Here's my code by now:

```
$('.order-button').click(function(){
   var productName = $('.product-name').text();
   var productSerial = $('.product-serial').text();

   $('#msgsubject').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change'); // choosing subject         
   $('#message').val($('#message').val()+" "+productName+" "+productSerial+" "); // putting text into textarea
})
```

Seems to work fine but when i have two products and i'm clicking "Order" button on first one it sending text from two of 'em where second button on second product do nothing.

[Edit] Sorry - second one doing the same thig as the first one. Like in fiddle provided in comment.

I belive i just need to add something that tell jquery that one button click is for one product and it should take "Name" and "Serial" from that product only not all right ? But i'm not jquery ninja and it drives me crazy that i can't find the solution ;/ Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please

Comment: Sure http://jsfiddle.net/02gqLq89/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sending you like that because the class names are the same and you arent specifiying which one to use.

This is the updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/02gqLq89/19/

```
$('.order-button').click(function(){

    var productSerial =  $(this).prev('.product-serial');
    var serialtext = productSerial.text();
    var productName = $(productSerial).prev('.product-name').text();

    $('#msgsubject').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change'); // choosing subject         
    $('#message').val($('#message').val()+" "+productName+" "+serialtext+" "); 
 })
```

This is the new code. As you see I used this to catch which button im clicking and then i used .prev to catch the the previous .product-serial and get its text then another .prev on the .product-serial to catch the product-name and get its text.

Your mistake was you were catching all the .product-serial and .product-name not just the intended ones

You can also use .siblings instead of .prev

```
$('.order-button').click(function(){
    var productSerial =  $(this).siblings('.product-serial').text();
    var productName = $(this).siblings('.product-name').text();

    $('#msgsubject').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change'); // choosing subject         
    $('#message').val($('#message').val()+" "+productName+" "+productSerial+" "); 
})
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/02gqLq89/23/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do you think .siblings do better job than .prev ? Just wondering. Cheers

Comment: yes .siblings also does the trick.I edited the answer and put both .prev and .sibling. Cheers :)